# psychopg opening cursor with "with" statement throws exception

Tags: python, python-2.7

Well. This error only happens on my AWS server (ubuntu) and works on my local BunsenLabs.

This is the class constructor and the line where I get the error:

```
def __init__(self, conn):
    self.conn = conn

...

def dropdb(self):
  with self.conn.cursor() as cur:
    print "cur open"
    #some cur.execute here that never gets executed
```

If I print the exception is shows just '__exit__'. Tried searching for it but I get a completely different problem.

I tried manually opening a cursor and it worked:

```
def __init__(self, conn):
    self.conn = conn
    cur = self.conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("create table bleh(a integer);")
    cur.close()
    print "done"
```

But it stills die at that with statement. What's wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Remove the package via apt `$apt-get remove python-psychopg2`, installed pip, and installed again as `$pip install psychopg2` then it showed the problem:

`Error: You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.`

So I ran

```
$sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.3
$pip install psychopg2
```

And it worked.